# Multilayer backpropagation with NETLAB toolbox

Tags: matlab

I am trying to use the `NETLAB` toolbox to train a 3-layer (input,hidden,output) feed-forward backpropagation Neural Network. Unfortunately I do not have too much freedom in terms of network architecture I can work with.

I notice `NETLAB` has the following functions that I need: `mlp`,`mlpbkp`,`mlpfwd`,`mlpgrad`. I am not sure in what order I need to call the above functions to train the network. The help manual is not of too much help either.

If any of you have used the `NETLAB` toolbox, kindly let me know. 
Also, if you know of other free toolboxes I can use in lieu of `NETLAB`, kindly, let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the edits, Claudio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find some basic examples on usage of `NETLAB` online [here](http://www1.aston.ac.uk/eas/research/groups/ncrg/resources/netlab/how-to-use/), the following is just the header:

> A Simple Program The "Hello world" equivalent in Netlab is a programme
>   that generates some data, trains an MLP, and plots its predictions.

The online demo is a brief version of a longer demo available with the program, and uses functions `mlp` and `mlpfwd`.

In the [downloads](http://www1.aston.ac.uk/eas/research/groups/ncrg/resources/netlab/downloads/) page you'll find that you can download help files, too.

If you get stuck you may (perhaps as a last resort) want to contact the authors.

**edit**

I understand that pointing to help files might not be what you were looking for. As you rightly point out, there is little documentation (perhaps more importantly no demos that I could find) on performing backpropagation, and definitely not with 3 layers. The available function `mlpbkp` backpropagates for a 2-layer network.

Comment: Thanks. I had looked at the help files. It is the same as typing `help <command>` on MATLAB. They are of very little help. 
I was hoping I wouldn't have to contact the authors. One never gets a reply, unless you are reporting a bug and quite understandably so.